# "Uncaught ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working with Firebase for the first time on a practice project and I'm having a very difficult time setting up the ability for users to log in to their accounts.

I've successfully set up registration but so far I can't get log in and check auth state to work properly.

The error I keep receiving in the console is 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined"

I've done some research on my own but the only answers I seem to find are ones saying you need to include the script tags for Firebase, which isn't relevant here because I have included them, or outdated responses from version 2.4.2

```
<head>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.0.5/firebase.js"></script>

<script>
   /*global Firebase */
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "omit",
    authDomain: "omit",
    databaseURL: "omit",
    storageBucket: "omit",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

The code in question is here:

```
// Create a callback which logs the current auth state
var ref = new Firebase("omit");
ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
if (authData) {
console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
} else {
console.log("User is logged out");
}
});
```

Comment: Probably should omit the key and config info...

Comment: @AndrewL Okay thank you.

Comment: Not from your actual code, just from the site because all this is public :)

Comment: You're including version 3.0 of the Firebase SDK for JavaScript, but the code you are using is for version 2.x. Follow the [documentation for the new version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) and the error will disappear.

Comment: onAuth() is deprecated in version 3.0 and you no longer instantiate Firebase object the way you did. Frank van Puffelen is right : you should follow the doc of the new version of firebase and you will be good to go. Good Luck!

Comment: These comments are super helpful and confirm my suspicions but what's strange is that this code came directly from Firebase. Anyway, I appreciate all the answers, this helped a lot.

Comment: @GreggClunis  please check once my answer. thanks

Answer (score 3):

As Frank van Puffelen pointed out, and as per the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#get_a_database_reference_numbered), in Firebase 3.x, the root database reference is instantiated as `firebase.database().ref()` and not as `new Firebase("<path>");`. This should solve the uncaught reference error.

Fixing it will, of course, be followed by other errors in your code, as ALI MAKEEN pointed out. Refer the latest documentation. BTW, if you're using AngularJS, AngularFire is an excellent binding for Firebase, and it supports [user authentication](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/user-auth.md).