# Not able to save data in Firebase through AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

Auth is working fine and create user successfully, but not able to save other data of registration in the database.

Getting error

> ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined

[image]

```
 var auth = $firebaseAuth();
  auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
  .then(function(firebaseUser) {
          console.log(firebaseUser)
          var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + "users")
              .child(firebaseUser.uid).set({
                  date: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
                  firstname: user.fname,
                  lastname: user.lname,
                  uid: firbaseUser.uid,
                  email: user.email,
              });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
      });
```

**Update**
Firebase: 4.1.3
AngularFire: 2.2.0

Comment: Show your full code. Have you included all the dependencies?

Comment: https://github.com/faisaljanjua/weatherapp/blob/master/app.js

Comment: Did you include `firebase.js` file in your html file? from here https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web

Comment: As the error says, Firebase is not defined. Once you resolve that *then* saving to the database will work.

Comment: @nivas, yes Authentication is working fine, "Firebase is not defined" error after creating the user.

Comment: @camden_kid, how can I resolve?, seem everything is included

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37928878/782358 - Does that help?

Comment: @camden_kid, I was using the Firebase2x code, now its updated with new syntax but still have "Firebase is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

```
------------------
ignore few bootstrap references
-----------------

--------------Angularjs-----
controller
--------------
            var vm = this;
            vm.user = {};
            vm.anurag = function() {
                $("[data-toggle = 'popover']").popover();
            };

            vm.registerUser = function() {
                firebaseService.signUp(vm.user.email, vm.user.password)
                    .then(firebaseServiceSuccess)
                    .catch(firebaseServiceFail);
            }
--------------------
factory service
 function signUp(email, password) {
            return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        }
```